# Image-cropper causing weird border

Tags: php, image

I have gotten stuck trying to solve this weird issue with a simple imagecropper for a webpage. When the PHP is processing the cropped image and the new canvas is larger than the the original image there appears a small border around the edges of the original image inside the new canvas.

```
$x = $_POST["left"];
$y = $_POST["top"];
$name= pop_extension ($exportName);

if($size == 's'){
    $h = 200; //small max height
    $w = 200; //small max width
    $img_dir = 'small';
    $imgname =  $name.'.jpg';
} elseif ($size == 'm'){
    $h = 400; //medium max height
    $w = 400; //medium max width
    $img_dir = 'medium';
    $imgname =  $name.'.jpg';
} elseif ($size == 'l'){
    $h = 1000; //thumbnail max height
    $w = 1000; //thumbnail max width
    $img_dir = 'large';
    $imgname =  $name.'.jpg';
}
$image_size_info    = getimagesize('tmp/'.$exportName); //get image size
$image_width = ($_POST["width"] != 0)  ? $_POST["width"] : $image_size_info[0];
$image_height = ($_POST["height"] != 0)  ? $_POST["height"] : $image_size_info[1];


if ($image_width > $image_height) {
    $width = $w;
    $height = round($image_height/$image_width*$w);
}
else {
    $height = $h;
    $width = round($image_width/$image_height*$h);
}
$new_canvas     = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
$source         = imagecreatefromjpeg('tmp/'.$exportName);

imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $source, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height, $image_width, $image_height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($new_canvas, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($new_canvas, 0, 0, $white);
imagejpeg($new_canvas, 'images/products/'.$img_dir.'/'.$imgname, 100);
imagedestroy($new_canvas);
imagedestroy($source);
```

The $x and $y variables are the position of the top left corner of the cropper.